# angular ui-router issue when using parent state with empty string template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use ui-router with parent states that does't have a template. I found this [topic](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/218) where it's said that state need to have a template. so now my router config looks like :

```
    $stateProvider
            .state("customer", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/customer",
                template: ''
            })
            .state("application", {
                url: "/application",
                template: "<application>",
                parent: "customer"
            })
            .state("company", {
                url: "/company",
                template: "<company>",
                parent: "customer"
            })
```

and in html :

```
<ul>
<li>
<a ui-sref="application" href="#/customer/application">APPLICATION</a>
</li>
<li>
<a ui-sref="company" href="#/customer/company">COMPANY</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Running this code displays no error, but the pages application and company are not displaying a content. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point of having this parent state in the first place?

Comment: I have the accordeon sidebar and based on its structure I want to build a breadcrump. The accordeon has parents (buttons) which only opens menus (ul) so I thought it would be ok to build both, accordeon and breadcrumb based on my ui-router config. But of corse any other ideas are appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but that still doesn't explain what the parenbt state is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to provide `ui-view` directive as template for parent state. And you can remove `href` from your html, since `ui-sref` does it for you.

Altogether:

```
$stateProvider
            .state("customer", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/customer",
                template: '<div ui-view></div>'
            })
            .state("customer.application", {
                url: "/application",
                template: "<application></application>"
            })
            .state("customer.company", {
                url: "/company",
                template: "<company></company>"
            })
```

And you html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a ui-sref="customer.application">APPLICATION</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ui-sref="customer.company">COMPANY</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put the ui-view directive into the parent template !